# Consume data from KAFKA topic and extract fields from it and store in MySQL using python

Tags: python, regex, apache-kafka, mysql-python

I want to consume data from a Kafka topic with the following command as follows:

> bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic myTestTopic --from-beginning

Then this will output the following (just pasting top 2 lines output, but it will be many lines...):

```
&time=1561768216000&gameCategory=PINPOINT&category=ONE&uniqueId=2518Z-0892A-0030O-16H70&transactionType=CRD&familyId=000-222-115-11119&realTs=1561768319000&sortId=1&msg=SET-UP+PRAYER+%26+intercession+begins+in+just+30+minutes.&remoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1&userAgent=HTTP&
&uniqueId=872541806296826880&time=1571988786000&gameCategory=NOTIFY&category=TWO&transactionType=CRD&familyId=401-222-115-89387&sortId=1&realTs=1571988989000&msg=This-is+a+reminder.&remoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1&userAgent=HTTPS&
```

I want to consume the following from the output:

- realTs
- familyId
- msg
- uniqueId

and you can see that each element is seperated by an ampersand ('&'). They are not always in same index/place so I'm not sure if I need a regex? Eventually when I do the query on a local running MySQL, i'd see this:

**describe testTable;**

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| realTs   | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| familyId | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| msg      | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| uniqueId | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

**SELECT * FROM testTable;**

```
+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| realTs        | familyId          | msg                                                       | uniqueId                |
+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1561768319000 | 000-222-115-11119 | SET-UP+PRAYER+%26+intercession+begins+in+just+30+minutes. | 2518Z-0892A-0030O-16H70 |
| 1571988989000 | 401-222-115-89387 | This-is+a+reminder.                                       | 872541806296826880      |
+---------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

What do I have so far?
I have a mysql-connector with python where I can connect to a local mysql etc, but i'm struggling with parsing this and inserting it...

Comment: FWIW, I would suggest using existing solutions for writing to a database such as Kafka Connect as it provides better fault tolerance and database session management... If you must use Python, you can parse the data in a framework like Faust and write back into  a secondary Kafka topic, which then would be cleanly writable to a database or consumed by another application that no longer needs to be responsible for parsing anything

Answer (score 0):

With Python, you can use `urllib.parse.parse_qs` to retrieve URL query string components in a Python dictionary that you can iterate later to insert data in your MySQL database.

For instance:

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs
line = "&time=1561768216000&gameCategory=PINPOINT&category=ONE&uniqueId=2518Z-0892A-0030O-16H70&transactionType=CRD&familyId=000-222-115-11119&realTs=1561768319000&sortId=1&msg=SET-UP+PRAYER+%26+intercession+begins+in+just+30+minutes.&remoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1&userAgent=HTTP&uniqueId=872541806296826880&time=1571988786000&gameCategory=NOTIFY&category=TWO&transactionType=CRD&familyId=401-222-115-89387&sortId=1&realTs=1571988989000&msg=This-is+a+reminder.&remoteIpAddress=127.0.0.1&userAgent=HTTPS&"

o = parse_qs(line)

print(o)
```

Result:

```
{'time': ['1561768216000', '1571988786000'], 'gameCategory': ['PINPOINT', 'NOTIFY'], 'category': ['ONE', 'TWO'], 'uniqueId': ['2518Z-0892A-0030O-16H70', '872541806296826880'], 'transactionType': ['CRD', 'CRD'], 'familyId': ['000-222-115-11119', '401-222-115-89387'], 'realTs': ['1561768319000', '1571988989000'], 'sortId': ['1', '1'], 'msg': ['SET-UP PRAYER & intercession begins in just 30 minutes.', 'This-is a reminder.'], 'remoteIpAddress': ['127.0.0.1', '127.0.0.1'], 'userAgent': ['HTTP', 'HTTPS']}
```